# Intermittent start 1999 Toyota Tacoma 4cyl

Tags: electrical, toyota, starting, tacoma

A few weeks ago I had an intermittant starting issue where the motor would start to turn but wouldn't fully turn over, it would just click. I took it to the mechanic, they said it needed a new battery/ cleaning terminals, and they checked the started motor and said that was fine. Now I've had a couple starts where the engine turns but doesn't start, and there is no click from the relay, so far turning the key again has started the car (2-3 times out of 50 or so starts).

I checked the battery while starting, 12.6 nominal, 10.6 under max load, 13-14 when the alternator kicks in, which seems normal. The car doesn't make any attempt to turn when out of park, so I think that means the neutral safety switch is fine. Is there anything this description seems to point to?

Comment: Have you cleaned the plugs?

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this symptom is intermittent failure of the electrical contacts in the starter solenoid. 
Removal and disassembly of the starter is required to confirm this

Comment: Had the same issue with my 95 Pathfinder. New starter solved the problem.